# Python regex to fix multiple types of encoded data

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I am scraping data from a website and I am trying to create a table from the data on the website. However the webpages may have multiple structures and therefore I am having trouble with doing this.

the 2 different types of structues I have come across so far are:

```
text1 = ['\nPie\n    Type\n\xa0\nMain\n    Ingrediënt\n\xa0\nCountry\n    of Origin', '\nApplie\n    Pie\n\xa0\nApples\n\xa0\nUnited\n    Kingdom']
```

and

```
text2 = ['\n\nPie Type\n\n\nMain Ingrediënt\n\n\nCountry of Origin\n\n', '\n\nApple Pie\n\n\nApples\n\n\nUnited Kingdom\n\n']
```

so far, using the following code:

```
for x in range(len(text1)):
try:
    y = text1[x].strip().split('\xa0')
    tlist = []
    for p in y:
        lst = p.replace('\n    ', ' ').replace('\n', '')
        tlist.append(lst)
    dflist.append(tlist)
except:
    dflist.append('X')
```

text1 will return the following output:

```
[['Pie Type', 'Main Ingrediënt', 'Country of Origin'], ['Applie Pie', 'Apples', 'United Kingdom']]
```

which is also what I would like text 2 to return. but using the same code on text2 will return:

```
[['Pie TypeMain IngrediëntCountry of Origin'], ['Apple PieApplesUnited Kingdom']]
```

because it contains `\n\n\n` instead of `\n\xa0\n`.

I have tried using a if statement to figure out whether the data contains either of the 2, but that does not seem to work if i use `if '\xa0' in text1:`.

Can anyone help me with either a regex function that can turn both of these in the desired structure, or help me come up with another way to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks to everyone who responded to this question timely. Unfortunately none of your answers provided me with the results i would like, but I answerd my own question. Will accept it as an answer in 2 days when stackoverflow allows me to unless I receive another answer that works.

EDIT:
Both Suneesh Jacob and RJ Adriaansen provided a working solution for this problem with an efficient code. I decided to time the answers and accept the fastest one as the best one.

results:

```
def decode(data):
return [[j.replace('\n    ',' ').strip() for j in re.split(r'\n\n\n|\n\xa0\n',i)] for i in data]

result:
0.07250859999999999
```

and

```
def clean_list(lst):
    lst = [re.split('\n\n\n|\n\xa0\n',i) for i in lst]
    return [[' '.join(i.split()) for i in sublist] for sublist in lst]

result:
0.0712564
```

thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex you can specify multiple delimiters:

```
import re

def clean_list(lst):
    lst = [re.split('\n\n\n|\n\xa0\n',i) for i in lst]
    return [[' '.join(i.split()) for i in sublist] for sublist in lst]
```

`print(clean_list(text1), clean_list(text2))`:

```
[['Pie Type', 'Main Ingrediënt', 'Country of Origin'], ['Applie Pie', 'Apples', 'United Kingdom']]
[['Pie Type', 'Main Ingrediënt', 'Country of Origin'], ['Apple Pie', 'Apples', 'United Kingdom']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this does not provide me with the output that I would like, since I would like to receive a list of lists [['Pie Type', 'Main Ingrediënt', 'Country of Origin'], ['Applie Pie', 'Apples', 'United Kingdom']]

Comment: No worries, I've fixed this with a minor edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```py
import re

text1 = ['\nPie\n    Type\n\xa0\nMain\n    Ingrediënt\n\xa0\nCountry\n    of Origin', '\nApplie\n    Pie\n\xa0\nApples\n\xa0\nUnited\n    Kingdom']
text2 = ['\n\nPie Type\n\n\nMain Ingrediënt\n\n\nCountry of Origin\n\n', '\n\nApple Pie\n\n\nApples\n\n\nUnited Kingdom\n\n']

def decode(data):
    return [[j.replace('\n    ',' ').strip() for j in re.split(r'\n\n\n|\n\xa0\n',i)] for i in data]

print(decode(text1))
print(decode(text2))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this only works for the second text, but the first text contains \xa0 so the .split('\n\n\n') does not work for the first text. I would like it to work for both

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question. I understand now. And I have edited the answer now.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, this outputs [['PieType', 'MainIngrediënt', 'Countryof Origin'], ['AppliePie', 'Apples', 'UnitedKingdom']] (notice the space bars missing between the names. 'ApplePie' and 'Apple Pie')

Comment: Yea, sorry, i had entered `''` instead of `' '` in the code. Now i fixed it. It should work now

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for your feedback that helped me in fixing the bug in the code i posted.

Answer (score 1):

no need for a regex in your case simply do this and add a replace before the split

```
 y = text1[x].strip().replace("\n\n\n",'\n\xa0\n').split('\xa0')
```

instead of

```
y = text1[x].strip().split('\xa0')
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this does not provide me with the output that I am looking for, since it gives me [[''], ['A']]

Comment: sorry added an extra[x] try now

Answer (score 1):

Alright so after messing around for a while I was able to figure out my issue. Thanks for everyone who responded to this question, but unfortunately none of your answers provided the results I wanted. I will comment on your answers what the output was.

For my issue specifically, the problem was:

```
if '\n\n\n' in text1:
```

Does not work, since text1 is a list. It should be:

```
if '\n\n\n' in text1[0]:
```

I can't believe this took me 3 hours :/.

The code that wound up working for me was:

```
dflist = []
for x in range(len(text1)):
    try:
        if '\xa0' in text1[0]:
            y = text1[x].strip().split('\xa0')
        if "\n\n\n" in text1[0]:
            y = text1[x].strip().split('\n\n\n')
        tlist = []
        for p in y:
            lst = p.replace('\n    ', ' ').replace('\n', '')
            tlist.append(lst)
        dflist.append(tlist)
    except:
        dflist.append('X')
```

EDIT:
After this post, everyone who initially answered my question updated their answers and all of them seem to work now. I provided a timeit in my question to show the one which works the fastest and accepted that one as the answer.